# Option to open files from the Trash

Tags: finder, trash

When we double-click or ⌘O a file in the Trash, we’re greeted with a message that it cannot be opened.

[image]

But there it no technical reason for this, as evidenced by the fact we can circumvent this limitation in a number of ways (such as opening it via an app’s `Open` dialog, or the Terminal).

But I’d rather be able to open them with ⌘O or double-click. Note *I’m not interested in solutions that require an external script or a new shortcut*.

Is there an option to disable the default behaviour (that leads to the dialog)? Seems like a candidate for a `defaults write` solution.

Comment: It‘s probably a rather unlikely use case, editing files which basically already have been deleted :-)

Comment: @nohillside Nobody mentioned editing. It’s perfectly valid to want to open a file in the Trash to make sure it’s the one we want to recover.

Comment: Why do you want to open it? That would imply potentially editing & saving the edits. If you just want to see what it is, either view Trash in Column view with Preview switched on, or tap the spacebar to QuickLook.

Comment: @Tetsujin No, it doesn’t imply editing. You’re assuming. I want to, for example, open a file that QuickLook can’t natively preview (like MKV). And even if I wanted to edit the file, so what? The Trash is nothing more than a glorified directory. I can edit files in it from the Terminal just fine. I don’t want workarounds **and I say as much in the question**.

Comment: It might just be easier to work *with* the system, not against it. Dragging a file from the trash onto the desktop takes a second or two.

Comment: @nohillside This has been bothering me for over a decade. Telling me to keep doing what I’ve been doing doesn’t help in the slightest. I know what I want to do, **and that’s what I asked clearly**. Either you: know how to do it or know for a fact it can’t be done. Every other answer adds nothing.

Comment: It can't be done without an external script, a utility like Keyboard Maestro, or some other additional support. Can't give you a reference on that (hard to find references for things *which are not there*) though.

Comment: Also please keep in mind that questions on AD are more valuable if they apply to a wider audience. I understand your constraints, but others might be happy to know alternative solutions (even if they won't be acceptable for you). That's why I removed the last part of your question.

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to verify whether it is the correct file to delete (especially with generic file names like `FullSizeRender.jpg`): You can still engage QuickLook on files in the trash by tapping <kbd>Space</kbd>.

Comment: No, I don’t just want to verify if it is the correct file. That was an example. Your answer also ignores file types that QuickLook can’t handle by default (like MKV).